# Injected data list (CSV) to cross join

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I'm often given a CSV of data to extract from the database. Sometimes, the user wants something like a count of all rows that match, with NULLs for missing data.

Example: An `orders` table containing `product_number` with a foreign key to the `products` table, then a CSV of certain `product_numbers` to find total orders (0/null if no orders).

I want to write a query like this:

```
select count(orders.id) as orders,orders.product_number
from orders
     cross join ( inserted list of product_numbers ) as products
```

But I can't find a function that turns `1, 2, 3, ... 10` into `select 1 union select 2 ... union select 10`, so the query is usually:

```
select orders.product_number,count(orders.id) as orders
from products
    left join orders on products.product_number=orders.product_number
where products.product_number in([huge csv])
group by products.product_number
```

Is there a way to use an injected CSV in something other than an `IN()` clause in a lookup table? There's got to be a better way!